# How do I turn any regex into an complement of itself without complex hand editing?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

The following are pseudo examples, not real regex, but still an example of what I mean:

---

```
.* (anything)

-.* (NOT anything)
```

---

```
[A-Z] (Any letter A to Z, caps only)

-[A-Z] (NOT any letter A to Z, caps only)
```

---

**EDIT:** Changed inverse into complement in the question. Here's where the change was made: "turn any regex into an **complement** of itself "

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, I believe you mean the ***complement*** of a regular expression, not it's inverse.  The inverse of a regular expression doesn't make much sense; but if viewed as a function, I suppose you could say that the inverse of the matcher is the generator which generates all matching strings - or something.  On the other hand, the *complement* of a language is all those strings *not* in the original language.

Then, there are two views to consider here:

### Fundamentally

The complement of a regular language is regular.  That means it's possible to generate an accepting DFA for the complement (and doing so is very simple, actually: just swap the non-accepting state set with the accepting state set).  Any such DFA can be expressed as a regular expression - so in principle you can indeed make such a regex.

See the wikipedia article on [Regular Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) as a starting point.

### Practically

The typical perl-compatible regex syntax used in most modern languages nowadays does not have a complementation operator.  For a *complete* regex, you can get something similar by using the negative lookahead operator: `(?!X)` will match a string precisely when `X` will not.  However, this is a poor replacement for complement operator as you will not be able to use it as a part of a larger regex in the usual fashion; this regex doesn't "consume" input which means it behaves differently in conjunction with other operators.

For example, if you match numeric strings as `[0-9]*`, to match the entire string you'd prepend `^` and append `$`, but to use this technique to find the complement you'd need to write `^(?!^[0-9]*$).*$` - and the usual concatenation of such a negated regex is, as far as I can tell, undoable.

Somewhat ironically, the practical incarnation of regexes is *theoretically* more powerful due to backreferences, but *practically* less flexible since the language can't quite express the complement and intersection operations easily.

Comment: **@Eamon_Nerbonne:** +1 ...and thank you for posting an answer, AND reviewing the other answers too!

Comment: Don't you have to first convert the NFA to a DFA? Since an NFA accepts if any path through it ends at an accept state, you could have a string that terminates at both a non-accepting and accepting state. Reversing the two would result in the same situation, and the string would be accepted by both automata.

Comment: indeed: fixed.  That's actually a fairly major problem, because the conversion is exponential.  I wonder if there's an alternative that avoids that issue...

Comment: Hmm http://www.springerlink.com/content/v7udml0tcgt0l7pj/ suggests that the worst case complement of an NFA is indeed exponential.

Answer (score 9):

Just run the regex and logically invert the output.  So change:

```
if(/foo/)
```

to:

```
if(!/foo/)
```

Character classes can be inverted with a leading carat:

[A-Z] -> [^A-Z]

A lot of the special characters have inverses, too, if you capitalize the specifier.

```
\s whitespace
\S non-whitespace
\w word character
\W non-word-character
\d digit
\D non-digit
```

Comment: perfectly good answer, and clearly the simplest way of doing it, though it obviously only applies if you're talking about the whole regex being inverted; it won't work if you want to negate just a part of the regex.

Comment: **@Eyal:** Still thinking over your answer, which is different, but nice. Still pretty sure I need an inverse of the regex, not the output. Thanks for posting!

Comment: "Need" for what?  Homework?  It's not clear what an inverse would be anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Several variations to consider:

Match a string that consists of a certain set of characters: `^[a-z]*$`

Match a string that consists of *anything but* a certain set of characters: `^[^a-z]*$`

Note that there are some shortcuts:

- `\w`: any alphanumeric character (including `_`),
- `\W`: any non-alphanumeric character;
- `\s`: any whitespace character,
- `\S`: any non-whitespace character,
- `\d`: any digit,
- `\D`: any non-digit.

This can get quite complicated, for example if you want...

- only non-letters: `[\d_\W]`, or
- only letters: `[^\d_\W]` (i. e. "not a digit, not a `_`, and not a non-alphanumeric character)

---

Match a string that contains a substring: `^.*substring.*$`

Match a string that *does not* contain a substring: `^(?:(?!substring).)*$`

Note how we have to check each position in the string for the "not-presence" of the substring. You can also substitute any regex for `substring` to match strings that contain or don't contain a certain sub-regex.

---

Match anything: `.*` (if you want to also match newlines, you'll have to set the corresponding option of your programming language, e. g. `re.DOTALL` in Python)

Match anything if you don't know how to set that option: `[\s\S]*`

*Never* match anything (for whatever reason):

- `$^` (i. e. match the end of the string before the start of the string),
- `\b\B` (match a position where there is at the same time a word boundary and not a word boundary) or
- `(?!)` (match a position where it's impossible to match the empty string).

Answer (score 4):

By using negative look-ahead you will be able to handle most of the basic cases

```
/(?!(OriginalRegex)).*?/
```

Comment: **@Colin_Hebert:** How would I know when it would not handle "handle most of the basic cases." Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You first example makes no sense, but for the second you could use class character negation:

```
[a-z] --> [^a-z]
```

Comment: **@SilentGhost:** Ha, I know it makes no sense, that's why I listed it as an example. Thank for pointing out class character negation, and giving an example!

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to understand the definition of inverse of a regex.

> match(input, regular_expression) = {match1, match2, ..., matchN}

How would the inverse work? Should it be something like

> match(input, inverse_regular_expression) = {imatch1, imatch2, ..., imatchN}

If so, what is the relationship between the first set of results and the second? If not, then what is it?