# How to find string which is started with ".."?

Tags: ruby, regex

I was trying to find strings out which is followed by only "..",but couldn't get that :

```
["..ab","...cc","..ps","....kkls"].each do |x|
puts x if /../.match(x)
end
..ab
...cc
..ps
....kkls
=> ["..ab", "...cc", "..ps", "....kkls"]

["..ab","...cc","..ps","....kkls"].each do |x|
puts x if /(.)(.)/.match(x)
 end
..ab
...cc
..ps
....kkls
=> ["..ab", "...cc", "..ps", "....kkls"]
```

***Expected output:***

```
["..ab","..ps"]
```

Comment: Do you mean strings beginning with exactly 2 (and no more) periods?

Comment: Remember that . is a special character, you need to escape it in regex: \.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard - Yes I want strings only 2 periods at beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is

```
/^\.\.(?!\.)/
```

The caret `^` at the beginning means match the beginning of the string; periods must be escaped by a backslash as `\.` because in regular expressions a plain period `.` matches any character; the `(?!\.)` is a negative look-ahead meaning the next character is not a period. So the expression means, "at the beginning of the string, match two periods, which must be followed by a character which is not a period."

```
>> /^\.\.(?!\.)/.match "..ab"
=> #<MatchData "..">
>> /^\.\.(?!\.)/.match "...cc"
=> nil
```

Comment: Could you explain the code of your one how works in such matching?

Comment: \. because you have to escape the dot (is like * for regexp, selects anything). So basically is "string_start:dot dot (not dot) anything else" read some regexp basics is easy. Also some regexp negation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977455/how-do-i-turn-any-regex-into-an-complement-of-itself-without-complex-hand-editin

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting on `/^\.\.[^\.]/` (starts with two dots and then not a dot).

```ruby
ss = ["..ab","...cc","..ps","....kkls"]
ss.select { |x| x =~ /^\.\.[^\.]/ } # => ["..ab", "..ps"]
```

Comment: can you explain your code,how it ignoring strings having started with more than 2 `.` periods?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `/^\.{2}\w/` as the regular expression.

A quick explanation:
^ means the start of the string. Without this, it can match dots that are found in the middle of the string.

`\.` translates to `.` -- if you use the dot on its own, it will match any non-newline character

`{2}` means that you're looking for two of the dots. (you could rewrite `/\.{2}/` as `/\.\./`)

Finally, the `\w` matches any word character (letter, number, underscore).

A really good place to test Ruby regular expressions is http://rubular.com/ -- it lets you play with the regex and test it right in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this at all, you can just extract the appropriate leading chunks using [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) or [`String#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-slice) and do simple string comparisons:

```
>> a = ["..ab", "...cc", "..ps", "....kkls", ".", "..", "..."]
>> a.select { |s| s[0, 2] == '..' && s[0, 3] != '...' }
=> ["..ab", "..ps", ".."]
```

Comment: The point is that you don't have to use a regex when simple string operations will do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
["..ab","...cc","..ps","....kkls"].each {|x| puts x if /^\.{2}\w/.match(x) }
```

Or if you want to make sure the . doesn't match:

```
["..ab","...cc","..ps","....kkls"].each {|x| puts x if /^\.{2}[^\.]/.match(x) }
```