# What's a regex that matches all numbers except 1, 2 and 25?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, bean-io

There's an input of strings that are composed of only digits, i.e., integer numbers. How can I write a regular expression that will accept all the numbers except numbers 1, 2 and 25?

I want to use this inside the [record identification](http://www.beanio.org/2.0/docs/reference/index.html#RecordIdentification) of BeanIO (which supports regular expressions) to skip some records that have specific values.

I reach this point `^(1|2|25)$`, but I wanted the opposite of what this matches.

Comment: first what language are you using? and second how about sharing what you have tried so far?

Comment: Why are you so intent on using a regex for this? It sounds like you should just do `atoi()` or similar and compare the actual numbers, or even just compare strings directly.

Comment: Actually regex won't match `numbers` it only matches characters. A seven digit character string will still be just an int.

Comment: Does your script/language support negative constructs? `if ( matched ) then fail`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Not that a regex is the best tool for this, but if you insist...*

Use a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!(?:1|2|25)$)\d+/
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com/39df2

Comment: then do us a favor and share what would be, to your eye, better/best tool for the task ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a pattern like this:

```
^([03-9]\d*|1\d+|2[0-46-9]\d*|25\d+)$
```

Or if your regex engine supports it, you could just use a [*negative lookahead assertion*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?!…)`) like this:

```
^(?!1$|25?$)\d+$
```

However, you'd probably be better off simply parsing the number in code and ensuring that it doesn't equal one of the prohibited values.

Answer (score 1):

```
  (?!^1$|^2$|^25$)(^\d+$)
```

This should work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

[See this related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977455/how-do-i-turn-any-regex-into-an-complement-of-itself-without-complex-hand-editin).

You shouldn't try to write such a regular expression since most languages don't support the complement of regular expressions.

Instead you should write a regex that matches only those three things:  `^(1|2|25)$` - and then in your code you should check to see if this regex matches `\d+` and fails to match this other one, e.g.:

```
`if($myStr =~ m/\d+/ && !($myStr =~ m/^(1|2|25)$/))`
```